Backbutton is closing the application
The device back button is closing the application. But the application back button is working. ie,
Navigator.pop(context);

Any pointers to fix this issue?

Please share your full screen code

Did you use Navigator.pushReplacement when going to the next screen?

I am using the following code to navigate to another pages Navigator.push( context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => NewPage(), settings: const RouteSettings(name: "New Page")),
)

Added code with custom navigation using Route Observers. Hope it helps

Try to use NavigatorObserver to monitor navigation events and implement custom back navigation behavior
Add navigatorObservers: [MyNavigatorObserver()] to MaterialApp
class MyNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    // Custom logic when a route is popped
    print('Route popped');
  }
}

Navigate to next page
   Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
   );

Navigate back with icon back button
 Navigator.pop(context);


Thank you. After this change, the application is not exiting and the user can use the application back button to go back. But ideally the application back button and the device back button should have the same behaviour and the user should be able to go back to the previous screen using the device back button. Is there any way to achieve this?
